# Rxjava minimum time execution?

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

I have an Observable A and an Observable B. Now I have to wait those Observables finish or at least 30 seconds. How I can achieve this on RxJava?

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Any code that you can provide ?

Comment: Thanks for asking the code, but I think my question doesn't need any code to clarify. For example Observable A has only item, and I want to wait until A emits this item or at least 30 seconds.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean maximum time? Can you edit your question to reflect this including the title?

Comment: @DaveMoten I mean minimum time. That I can use on a splash screen. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't said what you want to do with the emissions of `a` and `b` apart from wait for completion to finish but you could do this:

```
Observable.merge(
    Observable.timer(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .ignoreElements().cast(Object.class),
    a.ignoreElements().cast(Object.class),
    b.ignoreElements().cast(Object.class));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I really want to wait at LEAST 30 seconds. Like I wanna use in splash screen.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'll check it out when I back to my Pc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works perfect except I do not to use cast(Object.class) (It is cast but not castAs)

Comment: Worth noting that as you have merged the results together `onComplete` will only ever get called after **all** the `Observable`s have completed.

Meaning that if a/b never complete this will never complete.